# program-y AIML language support

Tags: interpreter, aiml

We have an AIML interpreter called program-y (https://github.com/keiffster/program-y). Anyone knows whether the interpreter supports different languages?

I tried with English, French and Portuguese. All 3 worked. Anyone Please let me know all the supported languages for this interpreter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is Keith the author of programy

If you write your rules in a specific language then that will work for any language

However it can also use google translate to translate to and from English, so supports every language google translate supports